# No builds available In Testflight for internal users

Tags: ios, build, testflight, user-testing

I've uploaded my build to my App Store Connect and it's "Waiting for approval", however, my intention is to test with few internal users.
I've got them all in an internal group and they should be able to test even if the app is not reviewed. When i go to invite them it stated there are **no builds available** and I don't understand why. I'm adding a picture of what my Testflight looks like. Is there anything I have to do?
[image]

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

Following the discussion [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128891), it seems to be a bug on Apple's side that can be worked around by adding the "ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption" key to your Info.plist

Comment: Your link doesn't work because of a typo. I fixed it: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128891

Comment: Oh my bad, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Info" on your Project Navigator to access the "Information Property List" or info.plist file.

Either find "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" or press the plus button to the right of the header "Information Property List".

Begin typing, after hitting the plus button, "App Uses..." and you'll see autocomplete list, choose "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" and hit Enter.  Then set it to Boolean and NO.

This will answer Apple's annoying government-mandated questions about Encryption when you upload your project to Connect/App Store.  Make sure you actually do NOT have added encryption-stuff to your project which violates export laws in your country.

Access this link for more details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations

[image]

Comment: After trying various things, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

@kjyv is correct.

The alternate approach:

Delete all the testers within your internal testers group who is not receiving access to your latest build, then reinvite them.

Give it a few minutes for Apple to propogate the changes and you should receive an invite via TestFlight to the latest build.

Answer (score 0):

After the uploaded build was processed, there was an option for me in the app store window to add the build, and after adding it there, it started appearing in test flight as well.